# Print columns dynamically in antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an arrray containing datas like

```
let data =[{name:'sweetha',address'12b',age:23},
{name:'neema',address'5b',age:19},
{name:'metu',address'rt4',age:29},]
```

. I want to print the columns into antd table. all the time records may change. so I want to print the data dynamically according to values coming from api. How is it posssible?

```
let columns1 = this.state.data && Object.keys(this.state.data[0])?.map((key) => (
            <span >{columns1.push({
                title: key, 
                dataIndex: key,
                //defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
                sorter: true
            })}
            </span>))
```

I try to do like this. But it doesn't helps me

Comment: are you trying to make columns of antd dynamic?

Comment: yes.I need to do like that

Answer (score 0):

By returning your API response keys in `title`, `dataIndex` and `key` you can create your own columns and then simply pass it to your antd Table `columns` props.
For Example:

```
const Index = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Array<any>>([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10"
    );
    const json = await data.json();

    setData(json);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!(data.length > 0)) return null;

  const columns = Object.keys(data[0]).map((key) => {
    return {
      title: key,
      dataIndex: key,
      key: key,
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};
```